# Scraping href using bs only returns the first link

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, href

I'm trying to scrape a table using bs and on one of the columns, there can be more than one link or href, such as the below example.

```
<td class="column-6">
    <a href="https://smallcaps.com.au/andean-mining-ipo-colombia-exploration-high-grade-copper-gold-target/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Article</a> / 
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kgew7tuLWCg" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Video</a> / 
    <a href="https://andeanmining.com.au/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Website</a></td>
```

I am using the below code to locate the them however this only returns the first href, and doesn't return any of the others for rows that have more than one href.

```
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 3000)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Scrape the smallcaps website for IPO Information and save into dataframe
smallcaps_URL = "https://smallcaps.com.au/upcoming-ipos/"

service = Service("C:\Development\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get(smallcaps_URL)
sleep(3)
close_popup = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "tve_ea_thrive_leads_form_close")
close_popup.click()

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

all_ipo_header = soup.find_all("th")
all_ipo_content = soup.find_all("td")

ipo_headers = []
ipo_contents = []

for header in all_ipo_header:
    ipo_headers.append(header.text.replace(" ", "_"))

for content in all_ipo_content:
    if content.a:
        a = content.find('a', href=True);
        ipo_contents.append(a['href'])
    else:
        ipo_contents.append(content.text)

# Prints complete scraped dataframe from SmallCaps website
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(ipo_contents, (-1, 6)), columns=ipo_headers)
print(df)

# Next thing to do is scrape a few other websites for comparison and remove duplicates.
```

Current output

```
                     Company_name ASX_code Issue_price  Raise                     Focus                                        Information
0              Allup Silica (TBA)      APS       $0.20    $5m               Silica sand                           https://allupsilica.com/
1          Andean Mining (14 Feb)      ADM       $0.20    $6m       Mineral exploration  https://smallcaps.com.au/andean-mining-ipo-col...
2       Catalano Seafood (24 Feb)      CSF       $0.20    $6m                   Seafood                      https://www.catalanos.net.au/
3     Dragonfly Biosciences (TBA)      DRF       $0.20   $11m           Cannabidiol oil                  https://dragonflybiosciences.com/
4     Equity Story Group (18 Mar)      EQS       $0.20  $5.5m  Market advice & research                        https://equitystory.com.au/
5             Far East Gold (TBA)      FEG       $0.20   $12m       Mineral exploration  https://smallcaps.com.au/far-east-gold-asx-ipo...
6        Killi Resources (10 Feb)      KLI       $0.20    $6m           Gold and copper                          https://www.killi.com.au/
7           Lukin Resources (TBA)      LKN       $0.20  $7.5m       Mineral exploration  https://smallcaps.com.au/lukin-resources-launc...
8         Many Peaks Gold (2 Mar)      MPG       $0.20  $5.5m       Mineral exploration                          https://manypeaks.com.au/
9         Norfolk Metals (14 Mar)      NFL       $0.20  $5.5m          Gold and uranium                      https://norfolkmetals.com.au/
10    Omnia Metals Group (21 Feb)      OM1       $0.20  $5.5m       Mineral exploration                    https://www.omniametals.com.au/
11        Pure Resources (16 Mar)      PR1       $0.20  $4.6m       Mineral exploration                   http://www.pureresources.com.au/
12     Pinnacle Minerals (11 Mar)      PIM       $0.20  $5.5m        Kaolin - Haloysite                   https://pinnacleminerals.com.au/
13          Stelar Metals (7 Mar)      SLB       $0.20    $7m           Copper and zinc                       https://stelarmetals.com.au/
14        Top End Energy (21 Mar)      TEE       $0.20  $6.4m               Oil and gas                    http://www.topendenergy.com.au/
15  US Student Housing REIT (TBA)      USQ       $1.38   $45m  US student accommodation                              https://usq-reit.com/

Process finished with exit code 0

The expected output should have three links/hrefs for some rows the 'Information' column, however it is only returning the first link/href for all of them. Could someone please guide me in the right direction?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below seems to work - it will look for all href items within content.a to allow multiple hrefs where available.

```
for content in all_ipo_content:
    if content.a:
    all_urls = [content.get("href") for content in content.find_all('a')]
    ipo_contents.append(all_urls)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = content.find('a', href=True);
```

This should probably also be a find_all, if there is more than one, so:

```
a = content.find_all('a', href=True);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @JustLudo - I just gave that a try and got a traceback error.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ic\PycharmProjects\asx-ipo-checker-master\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    ipo_contents.append(a['href'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

I'm still learning/new, but think that means it's looking for integers when doing find_all so it won't work?

Comment: Well ... your original example worked because you got 1 object back. Now you have a list of multiple objects, so logically a['href'] doesn't exist anymore. I haven't tested it but I assume you can just iterate over that list again (for ref in a). It would most likely be even better to add a breakpoint in the code and check for yourself what "a" now is/contains.